# Rendering Problems: Android Nougat requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later

Tags: 16.04, java, android, jdk

When I tried to create new application in Android Studio I am got a problem in my layout page, design part getting the following error.

```
Rendering Problems 
Android Nougat requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later
```

[image]

API24 selected automatically when opened it. 
And its working fine, when I select API23 manually.

[image]

The problem is I have already installed JDK 1.8 in my system and when open Project Structure it's shows correct directory of my JDK 1.8 path as shown below,

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 to run Android Studio, and when I check Java version am getting version as 1.8,

```
arul@arul-pc:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score -1):

You can install a later version of Java with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ oracle-jdk8-installer
```

Comment: you can see I already installed jdk 8, which already shown in question... My question is about Android Studio why not detecting jdk 1.8 when rendering

Comment: @AJ Google's Android Studio is very picky and has complained in the past for not having the latest version of Oracle's java.  The version in your message is showing `java version `1.8.0_77`.  The version after running the command I gave you will show: `1.8.0_101`.  In my experience it will run without the commands I gave you, but running the command removes the complaining message you are getting.